# user is not displayed on login screen after changing its UID

Tags: user-account, login

I've changed my user's UID from 501 to 1000. Now on macOS startup, on login screen, I don't see my user icon; Instead there is "Other" icon asking for username and password. How to get back my user icon on login screen?

I suspect the login screen starts looking for the users from UID=501. How to make **new** users take UID's from 1000 instead of 501 like Linux?

Comment: Why have you want change the User ID?

Comment: I just love 1000

Answer (score 1):

Setting up UID 1000 in macOS will not show the profile at the log-in window. So, to fix the issue, you have to put other number such as 1001.

You can find more details:
https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/how-to-hide-user-accounts-from-the-log-in-window-in-os-x/

Comment: Does 1001 definitely work - I would rather guess the number has to between 501 and 999

Comment: this is how my fate always is!